# use golang playground features to fake time during testing

Tags: time, go

The golang blog mentions two Go features faketime and timejump:
https://blog.golang.org/playground

The part that interests me is:

```
modify scheduler condition to wait for deadlock, then:
- check if timers are pending
- advance clock to trigger-time of first timer
```

I would like to know how I can leverage this implementation to run unittests with faketime. By this I mean many unitests that use time.Sleep. Testing in realtime is prohibitive since execution time adds up to hours. In faketime the tests run within split-seconds.

To be clear: I do not plan or want to mess up the runtime. I want to build a fake clock that works.

I am pretty convinced that the above referenced implementation works correctly in the concurrent case. If you have a idea, a tip or two on how to borrow this implementation and build a fake clock from it would be great.

My question is based on the assumption that google won't accept a pull request for runtime/time.go to turn faketime into Faketime or to add "func Faketime(f int64) {faketime = f}".

Comment: looks like in go 1.5 these features are now implemented in go (runtime/proc.go and runtime/timer.go). patch: https://github.com/golang/playground/blob/master/sandbox/enable-fake-time.patch this means to get this I need to recompile the go runtime?

Comment: checkout https://github.com/benbjohnson/clock

Comment: yes, you need to recompile the runtime to subvert time. Using the nacl build also comes with other drawbacks, unless you intend to patch this into the standard runtime build. It's usually easier to make your code more testable, rather than bending the runtime to test your code.

Comment: Another fake time package: https://github.com/jonboulle/clockwork

Comment: I am still convinced that the implementation used in playground is the correct solution to this problem. The clocks in the comments (by the way there are more) all share the same property: They fail to implement the deadlock trick described in the blog post referenced in my question.

Comment: That's the right way to make *examples that rely on sleep* work *unmodified*. But in production you may want to limit how much you rely on sleeps, and as JimB says, modify your code (to include fake clocks and maybe test code to drive them) rather than your Go installation.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is based on the assumption that google won't accept a pull request for runtime/time.go to turn faketime into Faketime or to add "func Faketime(f int64) {faketime = f}".

4 years later (Sept. 2019), that assumption might be challenged.

Brad Fitzpatrick [just announced](https://twitter.com/bradfitz/status/1169298386236784642):

> So we're moving the #golang playground from Native Client to linux/amd64 binaries with runtime faketime support under gvisor. e.g.

And ([tweet](https://twitter.com/bradfitz/status/1169321506247069696)):

> Austin's faketime #golang support is in master (1.14?).
>   See [`golang/go` commit 5ff38e4](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/5ff38e476177ce9e67375bd010bea2e030f2fe19) & its prior two commits.
>
> Note that the sleep is simulated and instead all writes are prefixed by a binary header containing the fake time, starting from usual Go epoch ([play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/Z35Vf8gIg4Z)).

See [issue 30439](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30439) and [issue 30324](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30324).

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EDpDthtU8AAXXd2?format=jpg&name=large]

> The context is the playground.
>   This is for use by the playground and might not even be documented or supported (kept compatible).
>   This is so we can replay sleeps in JavaScript but execute quickly server side.